# How can I change the function in this script from .click to .scroll (and still have the script working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the function in this script from .click to .scroll (and still have the script working) so that the action is executed on scrolling instead of clicking?

The js code changes the posititon of 3 icons/images that are initially positioned behind another image/icon. Like this: https://prnt.sc/gCyTQDqS_dtD   after a click on the image:   https://prnt.sc/CjAbwM1D1Cvw

Thanks for your help :-)

```
<style>
  
  .has-transform, .transform_target .et-pb-icon {
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
  } 
  .toggle-transform-animation {
    transform: none !important;
  }
  .transform_target {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle-active-target.et_pb_blurb .et-pb-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
</style>



<script>
  
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.transform_target').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('toggle-active-target');
      $('.has-transform').toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation');   
    });    
  });
})( jQuery );  

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: your js code does something on an html that isn't stated in the question. You are literally asking how to change click in scroll but didn't give enough hints on your scenario. I think the only answer you can receive is change "click" with "scroll" and good luck

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that would be important, but you're right. The js code changes the posititon of 3 icons/images that are initially positioned behind another image/icon. Like this: https://prnt.sc/gCyTQDqS_dtD   after a click on the image:   https://prnt.sc/CjAbwM1D1Cvw

What I did sofar was looking into similar scripts using .scroll and tried to apply what I saw on this script. I thought it would be easier, but I only messed things up. I am not a coding expert at all.

Comment: I changed .click into .hover and this worked well, but I'd rather use scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I think the best solution is to change the entire approach. One option to react to scrolling is to use an intersection observer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#result

See the little intersection observer demo below; the 2nd kitten will fade into view only when you scroll down

```js
const one = document.querySelector(".one");
const two = document.querySelector(".two");

function handler(entries, observer) {
  for (entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      two.classList.add("show")
    } else {
      two.classList.remove("show")
    }
  }
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler);
observer.observe(two);
```

```css
.kitten {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.two { opacity: 0; }

.two.show{
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}  

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}
  
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
scroll me
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="kitten one" src="//placekitten.com/100/100">
  <img class="kitten two" src="//placekitten.com/200/200">
</div>
```

Comment: I see I am not supposed to say 'Thank you' here, but I don't see where else. This seems very helpful and I am going to try this!

Comment: @Elisabeth You are very welcome! I think some people in general don't want to have any "extra" things in the question itself like, but personally I think it's completely nice and fine to say thanks in comments like this :) Welcome to StackOverflow where there are many kinds of people with many opinions using it -- this is especially true for "beginner" questions in my experience... I hope you have a good time in any case :D